# Determine 3-D coordinates based on TDOA of 4 microphones

Tags: python, algorithm, math, audio, signal-processing

I am trying to determine the (x,y,z) coordinates of a sound source given TDOA information from 4 microphones in Python.

[This pdf](https://trac.v2.nl/export/6400/andres/Documentation/TDOA/Ultrasonic_Tracking.pdf) is very close but works with TOA, which is then converted into TDOA.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869804/how-to-find-location-of-a-source-in-tdoa-method) shows how to get 4 non-linear equations, but I am not sure how to solve this.

[This article](http://blog.andersen.im/2012/07/signal-emitter-positioning-using-multilateration/) shows a multilateration solution with 5 sensors. There is a python version in the comments. Someone also asks in the comments if there is a 4 sensor solution, apparently there is but its not very reliable. I am not sure if this is a limitation of multilateration or of 4 sensors in general.

I have also found other 2D solutions: [here](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/public/etd-82597-03345/materials/aatique.pdf) and [here](http://srbuenaf.webs.ull.es/potencia/hyperbolic%20location/HyperbolicLocation.pdf)

I have the freedom of moving the microphones to wherever makes the calculations the simplest. Ideally I am looking for a function that takes as it's parameters the 4 microphones positions and the TDOA for each pair and returns a x,y,z source location/s (depending if there are ambiguities)

Answer (score 2):

Hey just incase anyone else needs this the following is a linear equation solver based off the formulas from

https://www.ece.ucf.edu/seniordesign/sp2019su2019/g04/Docs/CONFERENCEPAPER.pdf

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy

def tdoa_solve(delays_to_stations, stations_coordinates):
    # inspired by https://www.ece.ucf.edu/seniordesign/sp2019su2019/g04/Docs/CONFERENCEPAPER.pdf
    def error(x, c, d):
        value = sum([(numpy.linalg.norm(x - c[i]) - numpy.linalg.norm(x - c[0]) - 331.3 * (d[i] - d[0])) ** 2 for i in range(1, len(d))])
#         print((x, value))
        return value
    x0 = numpy.array([0.3,0.3,0.1])
    return minimize(error, x0, args=(stations_coordinates, delays_to_stations), method='Nelder-Mead').x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stations = list(numpy.array([[1,1,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,0,1]])) # the four sensors must be non-planar otherwise it won't be able to solve for the third dimension.

    delays_to_stations_list = [
        [0.00213434, 0.00213434, 0.00213434, 0.003696785],  # 0.5,0.5,0
        [0.002614022, 0.002614022, 0.002614022, 0.002614022],  # 0.5,0.5,0.5
        [0.00106717, 0.002386264, 0.002386264, 0.004400054], # 0.75,0.75,0
        [0.002502735, 0.003289239, 0.003289239, 0.003289239], # 0.75,0.75,0.75
    ]
    for delays_to_stations in delays_to_stations_list:
        print(tdoa_solve(delays_to_stations, stations))
```